# Test-path Condition PS - return code + logging

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, system-administration

I have the following script which contains a defect:
IF "$fswmain" is accessible I would like to return an OK and stop the script,
script works as fine but actually whatever the status is even if "$fswmain" is accessible he will till continue to set a new quorum file share witness with $fswmain value... I need to stop if "$fswmain" responds to test-path as True/valide

file configuration: FSW_pathConf.txt

`clustername=my CLuster`

`fswmain=\\myserver01\SQL-FSW1`

`Fswdr=\\myserver02\SQL-FSW2`

the PS Script:

```html
### BEGIN OF Passing as Variables, the configuration values separated with '=' and Retrieved from the indicated TXT file:
Get-Content '.\FSW_pathConf.txt' | Foreach-Object {
   $Vconfvalue = $_.Split('=')
   New-Variable -Name $Vconfvalue[0] -Value $Vconfvalue[1] }
### END OF Passing values as Variables
### Testing Each Path defined into configuration file
$ReadyFswpath = if(Test-Path $fswmain) { $fswmain }else{ $fswDr }
Write-Host "`r"
echo 'The Valid File Share Witness is:' $ReadyFswpath
Write-Host "`r"
### End of testing Each Path defined into configuration file
Write-Host "Now Setting up a New Location for File Share Witness: '$($ReadyFswpath)' On Cluster: '$($Clustername)'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "`r"
### As quorum file share witness is a cluster core ressource, we may need to switch the voting cluster type to node majority for being able to create a new File Share Witness
Set-ClusterQuorum -Cluster $ClusterName -NodeMajority
Write-Host "`r"
### Set a New Quorum File Share Witness location for the cluster
Set-ClusterQuorum -Cluster "$Clustername" -NodeAndFileShareMajority $ReadyFswpath
Write-Host "`r"
### Last Availablity check for new FSW location
Write-Host "Re-Checking New File Share Witness Availablity: '$($ReadyFswpath)' on Cluster: '$($Clustername)':" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Get-clusterresource -cluster $Clustername | where-object {$_.ResourceType -like "File Share Witness"} | get-clusterparameter -Name "sharepath"
```

Could anyone could help me with?

- logging all these actions into a file with date&time stamp
- with stopping the script "if(Test-Path $fswmain)" >>> retuns  as OK
  Only if $fwsmain return fails then keeps running next actions with "set-cluster" as described into this script.

Thank you very much.

Regards,
Willhem

Comment: ['logging all these actions into a file with date&time stamp'], then leverage Start-Transcript/Stop-Transcript cmdlets. ['with stopping the script "if(Test-Path $fswmain)'] This what conditional logic is for. If/Then or Try/Catch. See the help files or search Youtube videos on PowerShell conditional logic, if/then, try/catch, etc.,  for edification.

Comment: thanks I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to stop when path $fswmain is available?

Then you just need to use the **return** statement in your If-clause.

```
$ReadyFswpath = if (Test-Path $fswmain) { return 'OK' } else { $fswDr }
```